# How to get global styles inside in a <style> tag after running the build in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with my NextJS project. When I run 'yarn dev' I get the global styles inside a `<style>` tag, where I need them to be for page performance and to stop Layout Shift from occurring when the page loads. But when I run 'yarn build' followed by 'yarn start' the global styles end up in a `<link rel='stylesheet' href... />` tag. Hence my issue. Here is my code:

_app.js

```
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../styles/header.scss'
import '../styles/nav.scss'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

Packages installed

```
├── next@10.2.3
├── react-dom@17.0.2
├── react-responsive@8.2.0
├── react@17.0.2
├── sass@1.37.5
├── styled-components@5.3.0
└── swiper@6.5.3
```

I've been reading around and found mention of 'next.config.js'. I don't have a config file like this in my project at the moment... is this something I need or is there something else I'm missing?

My first time using both React and NextJS so any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution involves creating or modifying your `_document.jsx_` or `_document.js` and implementing the `collectStyles` to render the inline styles on your page.

This example in the Next repository walks through the process where the App is wrapped with `collectStyles` and renders the styles inline.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js

Note: This collects all style elements that are the children of your App, to selectively include `global.css` you have to look into the styled components API and parse through the `sheet.getStyleElement()` potentially.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here using styled-components, see `createGlobalStyle`
https://scalablecss.com/styled-components-global-styles/